# Material-UI custom required text on TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The Component allows you to set if the field is required or not, but I want to change the `*` symbol for `* mandatory field`.

Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't find anything on their API about it, but you can use `::after` pseudo-element on the asterisk's `<span>` element:

```js
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    "& .MuiTextField-root": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: 200,

      "& .MuiFormLabel-asterisk.MuiInputLabel-asterisk": { // these are the classes used from material-ui library for the asterisk element
        "&::after": {
          content: '"mandatory field"' // add your text here
        }
      }
    }
  }
}));

export default function FormPropsTextFields() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <div>
        <TextField
          defaultValue="My Name"
          required
          id="standard-required"
          label="Name"
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Also, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-w7d64) is a working example.

Comment: Providing a sandbox is great, but please also include the code in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will also include the part of the code solving the problem :)

Comment: this way is used for react hooks code, but the code am working on is a bit old so...

Comment: Ignore everything and just take a look at the styles I've written. You can find your asterisk element and apply the same styles as above.

Comment: @MichalisGarganourakis do you know how to do the same for the Select component?

Comment: Not sure, but we can try :) Update your question with a bit of your code to take a look.

Comment: Thank you for this!!

Comment: you can also add `InputLabelProps={{ required: false }}` prop to make it go away :D